# Parse.com Following / Follower Logic

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

Having some trouble trying to figure out some logic for the following situation.

I have built a friends system for my mobile app using parse. Simply put, when a user "follows" something they are put into a relationship. That relationship contains all of the people that the individual user has folowed.

```
User
Relationship - Friends (contains all of the users that that overall user has followed)
```

I can query who an individual user is following fairly easily:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"asg"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {

        PFRelation *friendsRelation = [object objectForKey:@"Friends"];

        PFQuery *query = [friendsRelation query];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", objects);
            } else {

            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

How would I query who is following a certain user, though? So, a users followers.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the user, use `whereKey:equalTo:`:

```
PFObject *user = ...;
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"Friends" equalTo:user];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
```

If you need to do a query to get the user then instead combine the requests with `whereKey:matchesQuery:`:

```
[query whereKey:@"Friends" matchesQuery:userQuery];
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. Note that Friends is a relation to User.

Comment: This should do it... It's the method prescribed here: https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#manytomany-relations

Comment: @rareDigital you'll need to give more details. It should be a relationship from user to user. Do you get an error or just no results?

Answer (score 0):

I actually did a bunch of blog posts talking about implementing a friends list that might help you:

- [Overview](http://timothywalters-devthoughts.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/a-parsecom-tutorial-implementing.html)
- [JavaScript part 1](http://timothywalters-devthoughts.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/friend-request-in-javascript-using.html)
- [JavaScript part 2](http://timothywalters-devthoughts.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/friend-request-in-javascript-using_20.html)
- [JavaScript part 3](http://timothywalters-devthoughts.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/friend-request-in-javascript-using_950.html)

The code samples are in JavaScript, but shouldn't be too hard to convert to iOS.

It covers the relationships, querying, updating etc.

The short answer to your question it to **use a Join Table** instead of a Relation so you can easily query from both sides of the relationship.

You can find a lot of information in the relations guide on the Parse site:

https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#manytomany-jointables

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is the PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser] method. If you are trying to retrieve friends for the current user logged in. You could use the same for retrieving the users that the current user logged in has followed.